# Bitwise NOT operation without the assignment operator - posible?

Tags: c++, opencv, operators, bit-manipulation

I know that I can do adding operation without assignment in this way `intValue++` / `++intValue` instead of `intValue = intValue+1`.

I would like to know if it is possible to do the same thing but with Bitwise NOT operation.

I guessed few syntax possibilities and the only that did not end with compile error was `~~intValue`. but I did not saw any change when I was printed the variable.

### Why I want to do this:

I know that if I using assignment operation while performing the requested operation (This case: "bitwise not"), Then according to my logic, this is what happens in low level:

> 1) Allocate temporary memory area for the data type
>
> 2) Copy the value of `intValue` to the temporary memory area
>
> 3) Perform the requested operation on the temporary memory area (so
>   the result is in the temporary area)
>
> 4) Copy the result from the temporary memory area to the memory area
>   of `intValue`
>
> 5) I'm not really sure about this: deallocate the temporary memory
>   area.

**Now, I know that this is not really a problem if the variable stors small value.**

**But what if the variable is an array of RGB colors (image data) ? This is my case. If what I wrote here is correct, then this means that it do copies in order to perform the requested operation. This is case of heavy data.**

**So this is why I want to do "bitwise not" in this way.**

Currently I am using function in OpenCV to perform the requested operation and this is how I did it:

```
Mat matValue = imread("bmpTest.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
bitwise_not(matValue, matValue);
imshow("test", matValue);
waitKey(0);
```

**Because that the second parameter of this function is `dst` (destination), then I am afraid that the way of how this function dones the operation is the 4 or 5 steps I described above.**

*NOTE: If there is wording problem in this question - please suggest me how to fix the question. English is not my natural language. I'm sorry in a case that I was not clear enough.*

**Thanks for the helpers.**

Comment: Depending on your platform, a smart compiler will elide that operation and replace it with something more efficient anyway.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Both `intValue++;`, `++intValue;` are equivalent to `intValue = intValue+1;`. `~~intValue` is equivalent to `intValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV is smart enough to avoid memory allocations and copies when they aren't needed.

Since your `src` and `dst` matrices in `bitwise_not(src, dst)` are the same, you don't allocate new memory and you don't copy results. You perform this operation in-place.

In practice, what happens is like:

1. *create* the destination matrix

   - if `dst` is equal to `src`, don't allocate anything. Make `dst` to point to the same data as `src`
   - else allocate `dst` the same size and type of `src`
2. perform the operation: `dst(i) = op(src(i))` (where `op` in this case is the bitwise not)

Note that:

```
bitwise_not(src, dst);
dst = ~src;
```

are not exactly equivalent, but at the end `dst = ~src` will call `bitwise_not(src, dst)`.

Comment: "if dst is equal to src, don't allocate anything ..." Are you sure? I opended "sources\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp" to see the code of bitwise_not() and I saw this code note inside the function: "/ if this is mask operation and dst has been reallocated,  we have to clear the destination".   According to my understanding and based only on that comment, I guess it always allocates memory for dst and then fix it's mistake by deallocate dst in a case that dst is src. Is this really what happens? If so that it means that it allocates memory anyway. it just then deallocate dst after (in this case)

Comment: This code note is inside the function "binary_op". bitwise_not use "binary_op". "binary_op" is the core of "bitwise_not"

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Regarding the comment: _if this is a mask operation_ (your is not) _and dst has been reallocated_ (not in your case) _we have to clear the destination_ (just set all elements to 0). Setup a small working program and step into each operation. You'll see there's no allocation in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to be sure that you know what you're talking about (that you familiar with OpenCV in low level and you checked it.)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the assembly generated for ++foo and foo++ is the same if you do not asign it to anything.
But as you said, it takes an extra operation if you do foo=~foo.
You can check this simple test to see what I mean: https://godbolt.org/g/he4xRP
Otherwise, if you perform a =~ operation in a local variable it makes it directly in the register where it is located, so is just one instruction.

As far as I know, there is no such thing as ~~ or ~= in c/c++

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it in more depth (I don't know assembly syntax) ..
"As far as I know, there is no such thing as ~~ or ~= in c/c++"  
So I suggest to implement it in c++16 (2016)

Comment: NB that link has no optimization on (with optimization the compiler of course throws away most of the code: https://godbolt.org/g/RjwBr4 )